# Understanding the Htop output

Tags: 20.04, cpu, memory-usage, cpu-load, htop

I am a recent user of Ubuntu. I am running some simulations in my Ubuntu 20.04 which don't run successfully. When I look at the usage, I see numbers like these.

[image]

Does this mean that my machine is using all the resources and it can't do more computation?

I see that memory is not fully used up. If it is not about the computational limit, I think the problems are coming from my simulation itself. Could someone answer this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are currently using all available CPU resources on 8 CPU cores.

You have available memory, but this doesn't help if your simulation is requiring CPU resources.

I would assume that the simulation has to run for as long as it takes to finish, while your computer will probably be at 100% CPU usage.

If it doesn't finish, it's probably a problem with the simulation itself, as you suggest.